# Why am i getting an unsupported operand type when using this for loop to calculate body mass indices?

Tags: python

Thanks in advance for your patience. I already have a two dimensional list = person_data. Each element has three indices: name, weight, height, in that order. Height is in cm, weight in kg. I am failing to create a for loop to calculate body mass index: ℎ()/ℎ()2.
  for loop below:

```
for person in person_data:
  for i, person in enumerate(person_data):
    BMI.append(person / person_data[0][2] ** 2)

print(BMI)
```

Comment: If `person_data` is a list of lists, then `person` is a list. You cannot divide a list by something.

Comment: Can you show us what your `person_data` list looks like? And `person` for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

`person` is a list. To get weight, use `person[1]`. Also, `person_data[0][2]` is the height of the first person. I think you should use `person[2]` instead of `person_data[0][2]` for the height of the current person

```
for i, person in enumerate(person_data):
  BMI.append(person[1] / person[2] ** 2)

print(BMI)
```

Comment: I don't think the outer loop is needed

Comment: you are right. I just copied and pasted the original code without checking it thoroughly. It should still work with the outer loop though.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, your `person_data` is a list containing information about a person which is also a list of 3 elements (name, weight, height). Then no need to use two loops. Just unpack the inner list to get weight and height. Just do it like -

```
BMI=[]
for person in person_data:
    # name can be ignored in this case
    _, weight, height = person
    BMI.append(weight / height ** 2)

print(BMI)
```

In your code the outer loop has `person` as well as the inner loop. So the `person` of outer loop is shadowed by the `person` variable of inner loop. Also, as you are not using indexes of the elements, no need to use `enumerate()`.

If you prefer list comprehension then -

```
BMI = [person[1]/person[2]**2 for person in person_data]
```

Comment: Thats very insightful of you to suspect I would later have a need for LC, I eventually did and came up with this: 
personalBMI = [ round(i[1]  / (i[2] / 100) ** 2)   for i in person_data]---- which is basically exactly what you did ( I am seeing yours now for the first time) only you weren't necessarily aware I required converting cm to m.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your list looks something like this...

```
person = [
  ['A', 85.52, 170],
  ['B', 59.8, 153],
  ['C', 64.4, 160]
]
```

As Kuro mentioned, Your loop should look something like this

```py
BMI = []
for _person in person:
  name, weight, height = _person
  BMI.append(weight/ (height **2))
print(BMI)
```

If you want vectored operation you can use pandas as well.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Assuming data same as above
df = pd.DataFrame(person, columns=['name', 'weight','height'])
df['BMI'] = df['weight'] / (df['height'] ** 2)
print(df['BMI'].to_list())     # to_list() for python list
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW! Thanks for your input everyone!. You all are SO far ahead of me. But that just  gives me inspiration. One of you asked to see the original list:
                `person_data = [
               ['John', 84.5, 184],
               ['Ryan', 81.8, 177],
               ['Bobby', 86.1, 190],
               ['Pete', 92.2, 188],
               ['Esher', 69.6, 159],
               ['Jane', 72.0, 166]
                                ]`
submitted answer:

```
for person in range(len(person_data)):
  height = person_data[person][1] / 100
  weight = person_data[person][2]
  bmi = round(weight / height (height ** 2))

  print(person_data[person][0]+'\'s BMI is ' + str(bmi))
```

I freely volunteer this code is not necessarily  better than any offered solutions, I am just sharing with you all what I eventually submitted, thanks to everyone's individual help.

***thank you all, each one of you posted something helpful in the spirit of being helpful and that really adds a lot of value to this forum.

Comment: AminGolmahalle Thank you for your review and suggested edit. I had to reject the edit because the edit changed an assignment operator inappropriately and would have resulted in the output not being correct. You changed an '=' to '+' in height = person_data.